# Ember-cli: How do I watch+reload a file in bower_components?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm developing an Ember.js app (using ember-cli) alongside a regular ol' front-end Javascript library, which is included in the Ember project on my local machine via `bower link` + an import in `ember-cli-build.js`. Trouble is, I have to restart the local Ember server each time I make a change to the library, which severely slows down development.

The big question: **Is there some way to tell ember-cli to watch and reload a bower_components import without restarting the server?**

For the record, the JS library is not the sort of thing that would make sense as an Ember addon, and creating a thin-wrapper addon just for the sake of reloading (if that's even possible) seems like overkill.

Comment: which version of ember-cli? Latest version should watch bower_components/**

Comment: I'm on 2.5.0 -- I'm not seeing an explicit changelog entry for a bower_components watch since then, but it'd be pretty fantastic if an update is all it takes.